# Pandas computing the data inside the column itself in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, fillna

```
I have come up with a problem where my data in the column has been recorded as 90-2,91-3,90+4 etc.My motive here is to add and subtract the data directly into the column itself. Datatype of the column is an object.

df = df1["ldm"].str.split('+',expand =True)

if df.shape[1]>1:
  df_2 = df[0].str.split('-',expand = True)
  df_2 = df_2.fillna(value=0)
  df = df.fillna(value=0)
  df_2[0] = df_2[0].astype(int)
  df[1] = df[1].astype(int)
  df_2[1] = df_2[1].astype(int)
  df_2['3'] = df[1]
  df_2[0]=df_2[0]-df_2[1]
  df_2[0] = df_2[0]+df_2['3']

df1['ldm'] = df_2[0]
```

[image]

This is my inefficient solution..I am looking for an efficient way to compute this in the dataframe.

Comment: You need to use pandas.eval method.  check here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html). It supports a limited range of operations, which makes it much safer to use than python's `eval` and more convenient than `ast.literal_eval`.

From the documentation:

> The following arithmetic operations are supported: +, -, *, /, **, %,
> // (python engine only) along with the following boolean operations: |
> (or), & (and), and ~ (not). Additionally, the 'pandas' parser allows
> the use of and, or, and not with the same semantics as the
> corresponding bitwise operators. Series and DataFrame objects are
> supported and behave as they would with plain ol’ Python evaluation.

```
df['ldm2'] = pd.eval(df['ldm'])
```

output:

```
    ldm  ldm2
0  90-2    88
1  91-3    88
2  90+4    94
```

Comment: Nice one! Safer than `eval`! (+1 soon)

Comment: I modified it to be possibly more efficient. ;)

Comment: @richardec Oops, I was adding details :p

Comment: Np, it happens :)

Comment: You can also vectorize the same operation: ```df['ldm2'] = pd.eval(df['ldm'])```. It might be more efficient if you vector is long.

Comment: @Bert yep, I edited that into the answer. However, I'm not actually sure if that's really vectorized? Because how can you get very vectorized with strings... but at least it preserves the structure if you pass it lists: `pd.eval(['1+2',['3+4', ['2+3']]])`

Comment: I am not sure how it pans out for nested structures. Not sure if it will work then.